# Run puppeteer function again until completion

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I've got a puppeteer function that runs on a Node JS script, upon launching, my initial function runs, however, after navigating to the next page of a website (in my example using `btnToClick`) I need it to re-evaluate the page and collect more data. Right now I'm using a `setInterval` that assumes the total time per page scrape is 12 seconds, I'd like to be able to run my `extract` function again after it's completed one, and keep running it until `nextBtn` returns 0.

Below is my current set up:

```js
function extractFromArea() {

  puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true
  }).then(async browser => {

    // go to our page of choice, and wait for the body to load
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 720 });
    await page.goto('mypage');

    const extract = async function() {

      // wait before evaluating the page
      await page.evaluate(() => {

        // next button
        const nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll('a.nav.next.rndBtn.ui_button.primary.taLnk').length
        if (nextBtn < 1) {
          // if no more pages are found
        }

      }


      // wait, then proceed to next page
      setTimeout(() => {
        const btnToClick = document.querySelector('a.nav.next.rndBtn.ui_button.primary.taLnk')
        btnToClick.click()

      }, 2000)

    });

  };

  // TODO: somehow need to make this run again based on when the current extract function is finished.
  setInterval(() => {
     extract()
  }, 12000)

  // kick off the extraction
  extract()

  });
}
```

Comment: on clicking on next page button in btnToClick.click() does it involve navigation?

Comment: There's no new param in the URL, it's all client-side. what you see in my code above, is all what makes it go to the next page. After `btnToClick.click()` runs, I end up on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what a while loop might look like:

```
while(await page.$('a.next')){
  await page.click('a.next')
  // do something
}
```

Comment: This gives me `Unexpected identifier` on `page`

Comment: Obviously this has to be in an async function and page has to be defined

Comment: I think @RyanHolton you tried to run the while loop inside `page.evaluate`. you should have replace the whole evaluate block with pguardiario's solution to make it work.